# Science Fiction, a Girl meets a machine capable of creating alternate realitys

Tags: story-identification

The book I am looking to find is about a girl who meets/finds a machine that is able to create alternate reality based on the probability of events.

The machine is sentient and I seem to remember it would look different in each alternate reality it created.

I read this book more than 13 years ago from a library and its name and author are completely lost to me. If anyone can help me find out its name. I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be *Mostly Harmless*, a novel by Douglas Adams and the fifth part of the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy trilogy?

The machine you mention is the Guide Mark II, a machine that usually appears as a bird, but can really appear in any shape.  The Guide is missing the "filters" that would let it percieve reality the same way as humans do, and can instead move in every direction in the multiverse, including all probability axis.

The teenage girl you mentioned is Random, the daughter of Trillian.  The Guide takes Random to an alternate reality where Earth was never destroyed.  It does this by manipulating probabilities to have a spaceship pick up Random because of some unlikely past events.  Random was born in a reality where Earth got destroyed by Vogon ships to make way for a hyperspace bypass, and she was born after it got destroyed, so she had never known the home planet of her species, nor had she met any human other than her mother.

Update: the book was published in 1992, so 13 years ago is not too early.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help b_jonas.
However that's definitely not the book. I know that it's not mostly harmless because I actually have mostly harmless on my book shelf. :)